# Isentropic vs. Isothermal Euler equations

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, entropy

I’m interested to model the flow of an isothermal and isentropic gas using Euler equations. For an isothermal gas we have that the heat ratio is just $1$, while for an isentropic gas it will depend on the gas.

The problem: Would it be possible to compare the isothermal model where $\gamma=1$ with the isentropic model where $\gamma =1.4$?

I want to say yes. The isothermal model is just a simplification of the isentropic model, thus they model the same problem just with different assumptions.
At the same time there is a little voice inside me saying no due to the $\gamma$`s being different, thus modelling two different problems.

Answer (score 1):

The exponent $n$ in $pV^n$ for a general polytropic process is called the polytropic index. A reversible adiabatic process is a special case where the index is the ratio of the specific heats at constant pressure and volume. It is not a ratio of specific heats for an isothermal process where $n=1$ or any other polytropic process that I am aware of.

Hope this helps.